# How to get drag and drop events in GraphicsItem which is placed in GraphicsScene?

Tags: drag-and-drop, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have graphicsview(attached graphicscene)setted as a centralwidget in scene i added 2 rect items(graphicsItem) (both are draggable). when i drag 1 rect item when its scene it gets drag enter event but when enters to other rect item its not getting drag enter event. How to resolve this?
Below is working example.

**graphicsview.h**

```
   class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
  {
    public:
      GraphicsView();
   };
```

**graphicsview.cpp**

```
GraphicsView::GraphicsView()
{
 //setAcceptDrops(true);
}
```

**graphicsScene.h**

```
    class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
    {
     public:
         GraphicsScene();
    protected:
        void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
        void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
    };
```

**graphicsScene.cpp**

```
GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene()
{

}

void GraphicsScene::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
  qDebug() << "Scene::dragEnterEvent";
   event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "Scene::dragMoveEvent";
   event->acceptProposedAction();
}

void GraphicsScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
  qDebug() << "Scene::dropEvent";
  event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

**graphicsRectItem.h**

```
class GraphicsRectItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
  public:
      GraphicsRectItem();

       static QString MimeType() { return QStringLiteral("job/x-job"); }
 protected:
   void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
     void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
  };
```

**graphicsRectItem.cpp**

```
GraphicsRectItem::GraphicsRectItem()
{
      setAcceptDrops(true);
 }

void GraphicsRectItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << "RectItem::mousePressEvent";
   setCursor(Qt::ClosedHandCursor);

}

 void GraphicsRectItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
 {
    qDebug() << "RectItem::mouseMoveEvent";
     if (QLineF(event->screenPos(), event- 
            >buttonDownScreenPos(Qt::LeftButton))
         .length() < QApplication::startDragDistance()) {
        QGraphicsRectItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
       return;
  }
    qDebug() << "drag before executed";

     QByteArray itemData;
     QString m_jobName = "rect";
      DataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);


      dataStream << m_jobName ;

       QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
       mimeData->setData(GraphicsRectItem::MimeType(), itemData);

      QDrag *drag = new QDrag(event->widget());
     drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
     drag->exec();
      qDebug() << "drag executed";
     setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);


    }

   void GraphicsRectItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
  {
        qDebug() << "RectItem::mouseReleaseEvent";
       setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
  }

  void GraphicsRectItem::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
  {
        qDebug() << "RectItem::dragEnterEvent";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
  }

  void GraphicsRectItem::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
  {
       qDebug() << "RectItem::dragMoveEvent";
         event->acceptProposedAction();
   }

 void GraphicsRectItem::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
 {
      qDebug() << "RectItem::dropEvent";
        event->acceptProposedAction();
  }
```

**Mainwindow.cpp**

```
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
 QMainWindow(parent),
 ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);
     m_pView = new GraphicsView;
      m_pScene = new GraphicsScene;
      m_pView->setScene(m_pScene);

      GraphicsRectItem *rect1 = new GraphicsRectItem;
      rect1->setRect(10,10,55,55);

      GraphicsRectItem *rect2 = new GraphicsRectItem;
      rect2->setRect(75,10,55,55);

     m_pScene->addItem(rect1);
     m_pScene->addItem(rect2);

     this->setCentralWidget(m_pView);
  }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
  {
     delete ui;
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean that, the left rectItem you are dragging to the right rectItem, in the case of it, dragEnterEvent happens. but from the right rectItem you are dragging to the left rectItem , dragEnterEvent doesn't happen?And are the rectItems themselves moving? I can't see the codes for moving rectangle itlself.I'm sorry, I'm from python world, but I take interest in this problem.

Comment: @user9402680 no... both cases not getting drag enter event ...

Comment: Oh, that is to say, only the scene accepts dragEnterEvent, but the both of two rect items don't accept it from your question and comment I read it again.

Comment: user9402680  yup